# Embedding react widget into another website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a widget that's going to be embedded into all sorts of websites. 
I want to build it in React, but i'm not sure what precautions should I take. For example with jQuery you just use the "noConflict" function that prevents collision with the other site's scripts. 
Do I need to do something similar with React?
Thanks.

Comment: see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this answers it. My widget is a standalone. I just want to make sure that when the other site insert my script in their site, it won't break down or cause the site harm because of their own scripts/libraries.

Comment: do you know which libraries? normally, it won't be any problem to render a react component and inject it into an existing page

Comment: Unfortunately it can be any type of site, so I don't. But thanks, that's reassuring.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible, and this explains it nicely: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html